# Nginx Invalid_parameter

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I've been attempting to utilize the load balancing technique in NGINX with the "slow_start" parameter, but I'm encountering an error where NGINX is rejecting the parameter as invalid. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance in resolving this issue.

Code:

```
    #gzip  on;

    upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:2321;
        server 127.0.0.1:2322;
        server 127.0.0.1:2323 slow_start=100s;
        server 127.0.0.1:2324;
    }

    server {
        #listen       8080;
        listen       9811;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
        }
```

Error:

```
nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] invalid parameter "slow_start=100s" in /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:38
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#server) states that `slow_start` is only in the commercial version of Nginx.

Comment: The problem is that the commercial flags are in their own section, and it only states that they are commercial a page and a half above the description of slow_start. Ain't nobody got time for that.